# Has contest theory ever been used to design real-world contests?

Tags: microeconomics, labor-economics, industrial-organisation, incentives

Contest theory, very much like auction theory, studies how people act in a contest and the properties of such a competition. There is a large literature that investigates different aspects of the contest, including efficiency, participation, total effort. However, while I am aware of many examples in which auction theory has been then applied to design real-world auctions, I have found no examples of contest theory being applied to design real-world contests.

Comment: Did you mean applying contest theory to *design* or *analyze* real-world contests?

Comment: @HerrK. Hi, yes.

Comment: I mean to design.